# How to install ckfinder outside the ckeditor module folder?

Tags: wysiwyg

I have installed both the [ckeditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module and the [ckfinder](http://ckfinder.com/) plugin. They work fine. So far so good.

The problem is that I have ckfinder plugin inside the ckeditor module folder (sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckfinder). Then every time I update the ckeditor module I lost the ckfinder plugin.

I'm sure that there is a way to put **ckfinder** inside the **libraries** folder instead but I don't know to do it in the right way.

Comment: Drupal Version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this helps:

> This module allows you to use CKFinder with the WYSIWYG version of
>   CKEditor. This module requires both the libraries and WYSIWYG modules.
>   Please read the installation instructions carefully.

found here: https://github.com/jrsinclair/Drupal-WYSIWYG-CKEditor-CKFinder-bridge

**Update 21 August 2012** This module has now been published on Drupal.org. You can find it at: http://drupal.org/project/WYSIWYG-CKFinder